# C: How to make fgets read a \n line break from a file?

Tags: c, newline, string-formatting, fgets

I have a program (console), where I put all the text in a separate .txt file.

I use `fgets()` to read a string from the file, but when the file contains a \n and I later print the string, it prints \n instead of a linebreak

Here is an example:

```
FILE* fic = NULL;
char str[22]; //str is the string we will use

//open the file
fic = fopen ("text.txt", "r");

//read from the file
fgets(str, size, fic);

printf(str);
```

If this is what I have in my text.txt:

```
This is \n an example
```

However what comes out on the console is

```
This is \n an example
```

Instead of

```
This is 
 an example
```

**Edit:**
in the file it's written as \n. I also tried addint \ or \t in the file but it would print \ and \t instead of a tabulation or a single back-slash

Comment: Are there 2 characters (`'\'` and `'n'`) or 1 character (`'\n'`) in the file?

Comment: in the file it's written as \n I also tried addint \\ or \t in the file but it would print \\ and \t instead of a tabulation or a single back-slash

Comment: `'\n'` **is** the linebreak/newline character. I don't see a problem at all. **Never ever** use a string from external source as `printf` format string! That is one of the most typical security holes in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fgets just sees the \ and the n as normal characters.
You have to translate it by your self to a linefeed character. Maybe with help of strstr() or similar.

Answer (score 1):

That's because escape characters in string and character literals are handled by the *compiler* when it parses your code. It's not something that exists in the library or run-time code for all strings.

If you want to translate e.g. the *two* characters `\n` that you read from a file, then you need to handle it yourself in your code. For example by going over the string character by character and looking for `'\\'` followed by `'n'`.

Comment: @LeonardoJeanteur So it's the single character \ followed by the single character n? That's what I mean, the run-time library or any existing standard string function don't translate it to a newline. You have to do that translation yourself.

Comment: I missread your answer sorry. I deleted my comment, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is scanning the text file and storing the data/text as it is in str string. The compiler does not take `\n` as an escape sequence. So if you want to go to the next line whenever `\n` appears then you should scan character by character, and if `\n` appears you should `printf("\n")`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char str[30];
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fic = NULL;
    fic = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    while(!feof(fic)){
        str[i++] = getc(fic);
        if(i > 30){    //Exit the loop to avoid writing outside of the string
            break;
        }
    }
    str[i - 1] = '\0';
    fclose(fic);

    for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(str[i] == 'n' && str[i - 1] == '\\'){
            printf("\n");
            continue;
        }
        if(str[i] == '\\' && str[i + 1] == 'n'){
            printf("\n");
            continue;
        }
        printf("%c",str[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When end-of-file is encountered and `gets()` returns `EOF`, this code will assigned `EOF` to `str[i++]` as if it was a character.  Not good programming.  Check the result of `fgetc()` like `int ch = fgetc(); if (ch == EOF) break; str[i++] = ch;`.  BTW `feof(fic)` is not needed here as it has detected problems too late.